# How to Remove a Specific Element and Its Child Elements from a String with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a string containing HTML elements as below

```
var div_elements = "<div id=\"pst_body\"><span class=\"quote\">This is the Quoted 
Text</span>This is the Original Text Within the Div</div>";
```

I want to remove the span of class="quote" and all of its child elements and also text within this span. And I want to Get the Result Back as a string not as an object.

Actually I want the following output

```
var new_div_elements = "<div id=\"pst_body\">This is the Original Text Within the Div</div>";
```

I just want to get a string excluding the span of class quote and all its childs, text etch.
How can I perform this Action with JQuery

Comment: Note that the easiest way to accomplish this will probably be to create an actual element first, then you can use all the jQuery methods on it just like you would with the DOM. e.g. `var elements = $(div_elements); elements.find('[class=quote]').removeClass('quote').addClass('original');`

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
var div_elements =  "<span class=\"quote\">This is the Quoted Text</span><span class=\"original\">This is the Original Text</span>";
var tempHTMLElement = document.createElement('div');
tempHTMLElement.innerHTML = div_elements;

var new_div_elements = $(".original", $(tempHTMLElement)).html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just turn it into a jQuery object and use the normal DOM manipulation techniques.

```
alert($("<div><span class='quote'>This is the Quoted Text</span><span class='original'>This is the Original Text</span></div>").find(".quote").remove().html());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZyMjD/